# Unable to get internet connectivity on Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, internet

I am trying to get internet connectivity on our Ubuntu server but its not working.

We are on a Dell PowerEdge server and have configured static IP using Life cycle controller.

When the system boots i see both the ethernet ports listed on the top right corner but both were set to DHCP in the config file `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`

I updated the config file like below

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno12399np0:
      addresses:
        - a.b.c.d/27
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: a.b.c.65
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

[image]

any help on how to fix this would be really great, Thanks.

Comment: I run Power Edge servers and can tell you do not set the IP in the Power Edge config the OS does not pay attention to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the given config is the complete file, I believe it's missing `renderer`, among other things. Try this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno12399np0:
      addresses:
        - a.b.c.d/27
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: a.b.c.65
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      dhcp4: false
```

This is exactly how my server config is laid out, and it works.

And you are of course sure that the default gateway is located at `a.b.c.65`.

Also `a.b.c.d/27` is a very small subnet, giving you only adresses from `a.b.c.65` to `a.b.c.94`.

Comment: thanks Arthur for your comment. Yes, i am able to connect my other computer to the same switch and point to `a.b.c.65` and the internet connection works, i will try your suggestion now.

Comment: that worked Artur, just one follow up question, I have set `a.b.c.67/27` under addresses, does that mean the IP address given to the server change from time to time say after a server reboot. what if i want to give server a static ip address so we can access it remotely which would not change.

Comment: I also see that under networks in GUI i don't see the ethernet connection i have setup, it shows only vpn and proxy, any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: `a.b.c.67/27` is a static IP address that doesn't change. The fact the the GUI doesn't show connection is probably because the GUI uses NetworkManager, which I'm not familiar with. [See here](https://netplan.io/examples#using-network-manager-as-a-renderer) for info on NetworkManager, and you could try if you can get it to work this way - or else someone else needs to give an input here. 